# How to calculate the charge acquired by silk when it is rubbed with glass?

Tags: electrostatics

Please help me in calculating the charge acquired due to friction.

Answer (score 1):

This requires more of experimentation rather than theoretical calculations, since a number of factors(many being not quantifiable) are involved:
1. Number of molecules in contact.
2. Number of electrons taken or given per molecule, which will not be a constant in reality since we don't have a formula for silk. It is a polymer
3. Relative speed, and attraction forces.

Experimentally, after rubbing, you can use an electroscope